# AdminUser and User, ActiveAdmin and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, activeadmin

I need some help to implement my system requirements at this point, i'm a "newbie on Rails". I have the two gems (active_admin and devise) installed and the interaction after some modifications is not what i want.

I want to build the AdminUser authentication using email and password (the default ActiveAdmin behavior), and the system User is already being authenticated with a document_type and document_number and password. It means have the two entities separately on the system DB with different login logic.

The problem is that ActiveAdmin uses devise for the authentication and i having problems with the /admin/login page form, it's displaying the document_type and document fields that gets from the devise initial configuration file. I defined the document_type and the document as the keys of the User.

The workaround that i found to make the authentication was to delete the document and document_type conditions and use the email as the important value for the validation. Now my AdminUser model looks like this:

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :login, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :document, :document_type
  attr_accessor :document, :document_type

  protected

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    puts "Conditions:" + conditions.to_s
    document = conditions.delete(:document)
    document_type = conditions.delete(:document_type)
    where(conditions).where(["lower(email) = :value", { :value => document.strip.downcase }]).first
  end
end
```

Sadly i have to say that this doesn't work for me. The authentication always fails, i tried a lot of variations without luck.
Researching i found the interesting idea to use the User model in both ways, but in this case they don't have common attributes and the roles are really different.
Anyone has implemented something like this? I hope yes. 
Ideas are welcome.

Comment: went through the text few times but didn't really get the issue. You can't login to activeadmin as admin_user? can you launch the rails s and show the output when login fails?

Comment: When the login fails the console don't show any error, it simply says on the UI that the combination mail/password is incorrect. 

The issue is that i can't get AdminUsers logged in into the system with this approach on the model. Sorry if i was not clear.